# Get UIViewController.title to show in modally presented UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I know this question gets asked a lot.

I've tried every answer (I think) and can't get a title to show up.

I have a static method I use to show view controllers modally.

I think I understand that a navigation controller gets its title from the `title` property of the view controller it is presenting, but I cannot get my vc's title to show up, and other methods I have tried aren't working, either.

```
static func present(vc vc: UIViewController) {

  // The navCtrl presents a vc, and uses that title.
  // I should be able to set this, right?
  vc.title = "vc.title" // doesn't show up
  vc.navigationItem.title = "vc.navigationItem.title" // nothing
  vc.navigationItem.prompt = "vc.navigationItem.prompt" // doesn't show
  vc.navigationController?.title = "vc.navigationController?.title" // nuttin'

  let navCtrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
  navCtrl.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  navCtrl.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  navCtrl.navigationBar.translucent = false

  // How about adding a UINavigationItem? Nope.
  // let item = UINavigationItem(title: "UINavigationItem")
  // navCtrl.navigationBar.pushNavigationItem(item, animated: true) // CRASH: Cannot call pushNavigationItem:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.

  // Can I set something on the navCtrl? Huh-uh. None of this works
  navCtrl.navigationController?.title = "navCtrl.navigationController?.title"
  navCtrl.navigationItem.prompt = "navCtrl.navigationItem.prompt"
  navCtrl.title = "navCtrl.title"
  navCtrl.navigationItem.title = "navCtrl.navigationItem.title"

  UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navCtrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

No matter what I've tried, I just get an empty navigation bar with a close button:

[image]

Comment: where are you calling this method ?

Comment: And how the vc parameter is passed ? Are you sure vc is not nil, Can you access the vc view property ?

Comment: It's a static helper method in my code, which means I call it from many places (to show directions, to show a login overlay, to show credit card preferences). I can tell the vc is not `nil` because `vc.title` and similar do not crash. The contents of the view controller also render correctly in each case, so I know I have the right vc

Comment: Also the view property is accessible, and has a nonzero frame: `<UIView: 0x7ffad821a080; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffad82006e0>>`